# How can I let a user control whether code is shown in a shiny rMarkdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to do something along the lines of

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

 radioButtons("code","Show code", choices=c("No","Yes"), inline = T)

 if (input$code=="No") {
  showCode <- FALSE
} else {
  showCode <- TRUE
}
```

```{r,echo= showCode, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
 # Main Code
```
````

But not sure how to wrap the code reactively
Is this feasible?

TIA

Comment: We recently added code folding to R Markdown: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#code_folding

Comment: @Yihui Thanks A step ahead as always Do you want to post as answer so I can acknowledge and close

Answer (score 0):

We recently added code folding to R Markdown (the **rmarkdown** package >= v0.9.5): http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#code_folding